# ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore in Xcode react native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I installed firebase according to a documentation of rnfirebase  but xcode throws me an error:

> ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore

my libraries:
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.6",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figure it out, the problem was that I was using wrong file to build my react native app after installing Pod in it. So the correct answer is to open `yourProject.xcworkspace`